# pyinstaller packing more then 1 files

Tags: python-3.6, pyinstaller

I have just learnt how to use relative path to pack an image via pyinstaller, but I don't know how to pack more than one file.

What I have as below, Script.py:

```html
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image

def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)

image = Image.open(resource_path('First.png'))
image.show()
image2 = Image.open(resource_path('Second.png'))
image2.show()
```

The above Script.py works very well. And then execute cmd as below:

```
pyinstaller.exe -F -w --add-data "./First.png;.","./Second.png;." Script.py
```

I know the problem should be in cmd code, but I don't how to rewrite the syntax.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Lawrence

Comment: `pyinstaller.exe -F -w --add-data "./First.png;." --add-data "./Second.png;." Script.py`

Comment: Thank you M.R. It works well!